# Unable to extend Windows partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I recently uninstalled Ubuntu by deleting the partitions it was in. However, I now have free space that I cannot extend the Windows 7 partition into. The free space is after HP C: and before the recovery partition, so it's in the middle. What do I need to do to expand into the free space? Could this be accomplished by deleting the free space first?

[image]

Comment: Is the free space in front of or after the Windows partition? If it's before, expanding is tricky, because that requires a physical move of the data. Some partition managers don't allow this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that. I updated the post. The free space is after the Windows partition.

Comment: Is it showing as used space, or "Unallocated"? If the latter, you should be able to simply right-click (from Disk Management) on the Windows partition and choose "Extend Volume".

Comment: Neither. It just says Free Space and is light green.

Comment: Light green means you've got an extended partition involved somewhere. You'll need to delete this if possible, before it will expand, because it needs to be unallocated. I'll see if I can find an empty drive to play with here.

Comment: So it does need to be deleted twice? I just wanted to make sure that I didn't delete something that could screw everything up.

Comment: Can you do a screen capture and edit your question with that, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, light green means it's an extended partition. It appears to be empty, and does not have a drive letter associated with it, so I think it will be safe to delete.

Once it's gone, you'll see an unallocated area, into which you can extend your Windows partition.

Comment: Always glad to be of assistance :-)